# How can I remove rust stains from enamel sink?

Tags: sink, rust-removal

Is there a sure-fire way to get rust stains off of an enamel sink?

Comment: I tried lemon juice and salt but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I previously tried using the CLR at Scott's suggestion, and it worked to some degree, but did not completely remove the rust stains.

I actually found the answer to my problem this week, pretty much by accident. I was cleaning a particularly stubborn patch on the tile floor, and ended up using a [Mr. Clean Magic Eraser](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0017SJA2S) on it. While I had the 'eraser' out, I figured, what the heck, let's try this on the sink. It removed the rust stain almost completely, with just barely a trace of it left in a few places. If I didn't already know it was there, I don't think I could find it at all. I'm not sure what this did to the finish of the sink, since the eraser claims to use microscrubbers, which I assume is essentially a very fine grit sandpaper plus some chemical action going on. I couldn't find any trace of ill effects, and it's been about a week, and no buildup has occurred in the area I scrubbed.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about "Sure fire" but a product called CLR (Calcium, Lime, Rust remover) is a good start.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll pick some up on my way home tomorrow and give it a shot.

Answer (score 2):

I've used CLR with some success.  You can also try a pumice stone.  The stone should be  gentle enough to not scratch the enamel, but tough enough to remove the discoloration.

I removed hard water stains from the inside of an old toilet pretty easily with this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Barkeeper's Friend.  It's a cleanser like Comet or Ajax.

Comment: I just tried this out and it worked very well - till I ran out.  I switched to Wright's Silver Polish, which worked...ok.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the rust seemed to be coming from the metal underneath the enamel. So I sanded the area to the bare metal (and sanded away all rust) then applied liquid enamel repair paint with a small brush. But the rust came back after about 6 months. Not sure what to do.

Comment: how does this answer the question? ... this site is not a forum ... you do not add your own question to where the answer is supposed to be ... if you have a question, the post your own question

Answer (score 0):

I've used Lime away with a hard toothbrush; then put the stopper up and the last little bit filled the sink with an inch of bleach and let it sit (WARNING: do NOT use these two chemicals together; one at a time cause it is caustic).